# pm2 commad always stuck at [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/$USER/.pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've been following [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2799) and till now my problem not solved, anyone can help? Any command of pm2 always returned

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/$USER/.pm2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm installing node using snap, that's why it didn't work, but it's working now if you install manually, cheers.

Comment: Hello @Muhammad Iqbal - I am having the same issue.  However, I only install node manually.  Did you learn anything that might help?

Answer (score 13):

You need to either update Node to a newer version or downgrade PM2 to an older version. This solved the issue:

`npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2@2.5`

Comment: Is pm2@2.5 is most stable version?

Comment: @JayminLimbachiya No but It's compatible to older node.js versions.

Answer (score 2):

I am having this issue on window 10 but can't solve problem by uninstall and reinstall pm2.

Finally I found a solution.

> **Run your command prompt (or) PowerShell as an Administrator**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, directory permission wasn't defined correctly for customized `PM2_HOME` setting

I changed pm2_home as follows:

```
# ~/.bashrc
export PM2_HOME="/var/www"
```

The problem was that the current user has no permission to write on `/var/www` directory. So I changed the directory permission in order to fix it.

Tips:

- I created `pub.sock` and `rpc.sock` (e.g `touch pub.sock`) manually when I see the error `axon:sock Got error while trying to bind Error: listen EACCES: permission denied /var/www/pub.sock` from `pm2.log`
- But when I run `DEBUG=* pm2 ls`, it makes the CPU over 100% by writting pm2.log (`axon:sock Got error while trying to bind Error: listen EACCES: permission denied /var/www/pub.sock`)
- **So create `pub.sock` and `rpc.sock` manually**!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when my disk was full.