# Broken pm2 manager

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

When I am trying to run any pm2 command I am getting next output:

```
ubuntu@ip-111-120-122-133:~$ pm2 list
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/ubuntu/.pm2
ubuntu@ip-111-120-122-133:~$ pm2 --version
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/ubuntu/.pm2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655380/pm2-commad-always-stuck-at-pm2-spawning-pm2-daemon-with-pm2-home-home-user

Comment: Did you installed pm2 either globally or in your package.json ?

Comment: I've installed it globally

Comment: Just to make sure, can you run the following command : `npm list -g | grep pm2`, it will find packages installed, and filter those who have "pm2" in their name.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-111-120-122-133:~$ npm list -g | grep pm2
└─┬ pm2@4.5.6
  ├─┬ @pm2/agent@1.0.8
  │ ├── pm2-axon@4.0.1 deduped
  │ ├── pm2-axon-rpc@0.7.1 deduped
  ├─┬ @pm2/io@5.0.0
  ├─┬ @pm2/js-api@0.6.7
  ├─┬ @pm2/pm2-version-check@1.0.4
  ├─┬ pm2-axon@4.0.1
  ├─┬ pm2-axon-rpc@0.7.1
  ├─┬ pm2-deploy@1.0.2
  ├─┬ pm2-multimeter@0.1.2